# With Go's webserver where does the root of the website map onto the filesystem?

Tags: go, webserver

Where is the filesystem "root" of a Go `net/http` webserver. It doesn't seem to be in the directory the executable is in.
By "root" I mean the directory I would use for, say, the `src` attribute of an `img`, without any path. I don't plan to do this, but it would help me understand the structure if I knew.

Comment: Not a big deal but someone just edited my question. I am not too familiar with the etiquette here but that seems a little, let's say, high handed.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Introduction

In Go the [`net/http`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) package is used to provide Web Server functionality. This is not a static fileserver, it is much more than that.

There is no filesystem "root" concept. The provided web server uses [**handlers**](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler) to serve HTTP requests which are mapped to URLs. A handler is responsible to process an HTTP request and to setup and generate the response. A handler can be registered e.g. with the [`Handle()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handle) or [`HandleFunc()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandleFunc) functions. The server can be started with the [`ListenAndServe()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ListenAndServe) function.

Read the package documentation of [`net/http`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) to understand the basic concepts and to get started. It also contains many small examples.

The Blog article [Writing Web Applications](http://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/) is also helpful.

### Static File Server

However, a static file server or "filesystem" functionality is provided, there is a [`FileServer()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer) function in the `http` package which returns a `Handler` which serves static files. You can specify the "root" folder to serve static files from as a parameter of `FileServer()`.

If you pass an *absolute* path to `FileServer()`, then there is no question what that means. If you provide a *relative* path, it is always interpreted in the context of the *current* or *working* directory. By default this is the folder you start the application from (the folder you're in when executing the `go run ...` command or the compiled executable binary).

Example:

```
http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/tmp")))
```

This will setup a handler to serve files from the folder `/tmp` mapped to the root URL `/`. For example the response to the GET request `"/mydoc.txt"` will be the `"/tmp/mydoc.txt"` static file.

Complete application:

```
package main
import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)
func main() {
    // Simple static webserver:
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/tmp")))
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

You can do more complex mapping using the [`StripPrefix()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#StripPrefix) function. Example:

```
// To serve a directory on disk (/tmp) under an alternate URL
// path (/tmpfiles/), use StripPrefix to modify the request
// URL's path before the FileServer sees it:
http.Handle("/tmpfiles/",
    http.StripPrefix("/tmpfiles/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/tmp"))))
```

Comment: Thanks for full and fast reply. I guess I still don't know where "/tmp" is relative to in the last line of your example: filesystem root? somewhere in the golang folder hierarchy?

Comment: @quanglewangle `"/tmp"` is an _absolute_ path. On unix systems the root folder is `/`. See my edited answer which details _absolute_ and _relative_ paths.