# Include js file in Go template

Tags: jquery, go, webserver

I started learning Go recently. I got a sample like as web app. I have:

```
/* tick-tock.go */
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

// Content for the main html page..
var page = `<html>
           <head>
             <script type="text/javascript"
               src="http://localhost:8081/jquery.min.js">
             </script>
             <style> 
               div {
                 font-family: "Times New Roman", Georgia, Serif;
                 font-size: 1em;
                 width: 13.3em;
                 padding: 8px 8px; 
                 border: 2px solid #2B1B17;
                 color: #2B1B17;
                 text-shadow: 1px 1px #E5E4E2;
                 background: #FFFFFF;
               }
             </style>
           </head>
           <body>
             <h2 align=center>Go Timer </h2>
             <div id="output" style="width: 30%; height: 63%; overflow-y: scroll; float:left;"></div>
             <div id="v1" style="width: 50%; height: 30%; overflow-y: scroll; float:left;"></div>
             <div id="v2" style="width: 50%; height: 30%; overflow-y: scroll; float:left;"></div>
             <input id="sett" type="submit" name="sett" value="Settings" onclick="changeUrl()">

             <script type="text/javascript">

               var myDelay;

               $(document).ready(function () 
               {
                   $("#output").append("Waiting for system time..");

                   myDelay = setInterval("delayedPost()", 1000);               

                });

               function delayedPost() 
               {
                 $.post("http://localhost:9999/dev", "", function(data, status) 
                 {
                    //$("#output").empty();
                    $("#output").prepend(data);
                 });

                 $.post("http://localhost:9999/v1", "", function(data, status) {
                    //$("#output").empty();
                    $("#v1").prepend(data);
                 });

                 $.post("http://localhost:9999/v2", "", function(data, status) {
                    //$("#output").empty();
                    $("#v2").prepend(data);
                 });
               }

               function delayedPost1() 
               {
                 $.post("http://localhost:9999/dev", "", function(data, status) 
                 {                    
                    $("#output").prepend(data);
                 });

                 $.post("http://localhost:9999/v1", "", function(data, status) 
                 {                   
                    $("#v1").prepend(data);
                 });

                 $.post("http://localhost:9999/v3", "", function(data, status) 
                 {                    
                    $("#v2").prepend(data);
                 });
               }

               function changeUrl()
               {
                  alert('salom');                      
                  clearInterval(myDelay);



               }

             </script>
           </body>
         </html>`

// handler for the main page.
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprint(w, page)
}

// handler to cater AJAX requests
func handlerDevs(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //fmt.Fprint(w, time.Now().Format("Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 MST"))
    fmt.Fprint(w, "<font color=red>Dev1<br></font>")
}

func handlerV1(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //fmt.Fprint(w, time.Now().Format("Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 MST"))
    fmt.Fprint(w, "<font color=blue>Vertical1<br></font>")
}

func handlerV2(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    //fmt.Fprint(w, time.Now().Format("Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 MST"))
    fmt.Fprint(w, "<font color=green>Vertical2<br></font>")
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    http.HandleFunc("/dev", handlerDevs)
    http.HandleFunc("/v1", handlerV1)
    http.HandleFunc("/v2", handlerV2)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":9999", nil))
    http.HandleFunc("/jquery.min.js", SendJqueryJs)
    panic(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil))
}
func SendJqueryJs(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("jquery.min.js")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Couldn't read file", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/javascript")
    w.Write(data)
}
```

I couldn't load local `jquery.min.js`. When I wrote `src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"` it was loaded. How can I load local js file? I am not good at coding in Go and I did not write full code. So please try to explain very simple. Thanks in advance!

Comment: first thing I'd try is change `/jquery.min.js` to `jquery.min.js`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need a [`Handler`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Handler) or a [`HandlerFunc`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc) which will send the file content (`jquery.min.js`) to the web browser when requested.

You have 3 options:

### Doing It Manually

This is the more complex solution. It would look like in your handler function you read the content of the file, set proper response content type (`application/javascript`) and send the content (which is a `[]byte`) to the response.

Things to look out for: When reading the file, you have to specify an absolute path. If you specify a relative path, be sure the file is in the current folder (working directory) you start your app from.

Example:

```
func SendJqueryJs(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile("jquery.min.js")
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Couldn't read file", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/javascript; charset=utf-8")
    w.Write(data)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/jquery.min.js", SendJqueryJs)
    panic(http.ListenAndServe(":8081", nil))
}
```

The above example is capable of serving only 1 file: `jquery.min.js` for the request:

```
http://localhost:8081/jquery.min.js
```

### Utilizing `http.ServeFile()`

This is much easier: The function [`http.ServeFile()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeFile) is capable of sending the content of one file to the specified response. You still need to create a function or handler to use it, but it does the rest for you:

```
func SendJqueryJs(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "jquery.min.js")
}
```

### Utilizing `http.FileServer()`

If you need to serve multiple static files, this is where [`FileServer()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer) function comes handy which returns you a `Handler` which automatically serves files from your local file system that are descendants of the root folder you specify.

This solution is much more flexible: it can send many files of multiple types, detects and sets content type automatically. The handler is also capable of rendering HTML pages for listing directory content with links to the files and to parent/child folders.

Example:

```
http.Handle("/tmpfiles/",
    http.StripPrefix("/tmpfiles/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/tmp"))))
```

This will register a `Handler` at the URL `/tmpfiles/` which serves files found in your local filesystem in the `/tmp` folder. So for example the following `<script>` link:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/tmpfiles/jquery.min.js">
```

Will get the `/tmp/jsquery.min.js` file from the server.

Check out this answer which details how to use/fire up a [Static File Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28745280/1705598).

Comment: It keeps getting message: "Serving from the file system? Add your files into the workspace.
less
If you add files into your DevTools workspace, your changes will be persisted to disk.
To add a folder into the workspace, drag and drop it into the Sources panel.
For more information on workspaces, refer to the workspaces documentation."