# GO - html file can't load external js file

Tags: javascript, html, go

I have a GO project which has UI written by html. In HTML file, I have written javascript, and I can install GO and load the UI successfully.

The problem is when I move those javascript code to an external file, and include it: . I only can build GO, but when load the UI, it has error 404 Not Found which is  "myscripts.js" file. The weird thing is on its header of error:
Remote Address:127.0.0.1:8080
Request URL:http://localhost:8080/subscribe/myscripts.js
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found

Please help, I can't find any answer yet for this

Comment: I include by simply writing this line of code in HTML file: <script src="myscripts.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: If those html files are fragments in deeper folders ensure that the script path is relative based on the final page they are inject to and not the template itself

Comment: possible duplicate of [Include js file in Go template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899675/include-js-file-in-go-template)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's normal if you only define handler for your endpoints.

You should add to your router the [`http.FileServer`](https://godoc.org/net/http#FileServer) handler pointing to the directory that store your project files.

Additionally, think about the `<base>` that to define the root of your relative links, which will prevent errors such as path nesting.

Comment: Thank you. I found a way which add to main() this line of code: