# How to set different content types when using HTML/TEMPLATE package in Go

Tags: html, http, go, go-templates

When trying to pass a value into `.html` code I'm using the `html/template` package.

However, I can't seem to set the `.css` content type that is referenced in my `.html` file. It is being served to the browser as plain text and thus formatting is ignored.

In a static `.html` file I can use the built-in `http.Fileserver` which takes care of content types but then templating doesn't work. I can't pass in the variable. It just displays as `{{.}}`

Is there a way to combine the `content-type` convenience of the built-in fileserver `http.Fileserver` with the template ability of `http.HandleFunc`?

Here is my code as it stands without using `http.Fileserver`. Note, my `Go` file is in the starting directory and the `index.html` and `.css` files are in a subdirectory `/hello/`:

```
package main

import (
        "html/template"
        "io/ioutil"
        "log"
        "net/http"
)

var Message string = "test page"

func servePipe(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

        dat, err := ioutil.ReadFile("hello/index.html")
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("couldn't read file:", err)
        }   

        templ, err := template.New("Test").Parse(string(dat))

        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("couldn't parse page:", err)
        }   

        templ.Execute(w, Message)

}

func main() {

        http.HandleFunc("/hello/", servePipe)
        http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Here is my `.html` file. The html page is being served without any issues. It's the separate `.css` file that is not being served (linked in the `.html` file) thus the formatting doesn't occur.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>

<body>

        <p>{{.}}</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Template.Execute()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.Execute) will "deliver" the content by calling the `Write()` method of the passed [`io.Writer`](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#Writer) which in your case is the [`http.ResponseWriter`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter).

If you don't set the content type prior to the first call to `ResponseWriter.Write()` (you don't in your example), then the [`net/http`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) package will attempt to detect the content type (based on the first 512 bytes written), and will set it automatically for you (along with `WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)` if `ResponseWriter.WriteHeader()` has not been called).

This is documented at `http.ResponseWriter.Write()`:

```
// Write writes the data to the connection as part of an HTTP reply.
//
// If WriteHeader has not yet been called, Write calls
// WriteHeader(http.StatusOK) before writing the data. If the Header
// does not contain a Content-Type line, Write adds a Content-Type set
// to the result of passing the initial 512 bytes of written data to
// DetectContentType.
//
// ...
Write([]byte) (int, error)
```

So if your `index.html` would look like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    This is the body!
  </body>
</html>
```

Then this would be properly detected as an HTML document and thus `text/html` content type would be automatically set. If this doesn't happen for you, that means your `index.html` is not recognized as an HTML document. So just make sure you make your template files valid HTML / CSS / etc. documents and content type will be inferred automatically and properly.

Also note that if it wouldn't work in some "extreme" cases, you can always "override" it by manually setting it prior to calling `Template.Execute()` like this:

```
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
templ.Execute(w, Message)
```

Side note: don't read and parse templates inside your handlers, for details see related question: [It takes too much time when using "template" package to generate a dynamic web page to client in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28451675/it-takes-too-much-time-when-using-template-package-to-generate-a-dynamic-web-p)

---

If a template served by you references other templates, they will not be magically loaded and executed. In such cases you should have a "pre-loaded" templates containing all the templates. [`template.ParseFiles()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#ParseFiles) and [`template.ParseGlob()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#ParseGlob) are good "tools" to load multiple template files at once.

So if your `index.html` references `style.css`, then you have to take care about serving `style.css` too. If it is not a template (but e.g. a static file), you may serve it using multiple options presented here: [Include js file in Go template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899675/include-js-file-in-go-template)

If it is also a template, then you also have to load it and serve it by calling [`Template.ExecuteTemplate()`](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#Template.ExecuteTemplate).

An example solution would be to load both using `template.ParseFiles()`, and use the path to "designate" which template you want to have served (from the client / browser side).

E.g. requesting the path `/hello/index.html` could serve the `"index.html"` template, requesting the path `/hello/style.css` (*this will be done automatically by the browser after receiving and processing the `index.html`*) could serve the `"style.css"` template. It could look like this (error checks omitted for brevity):

```
parts := strings.Split(req.URL.Path, "/") // Parts of the path
templName := parts[len(parts)-1]          // The last part
templ.ExecuteTemplate(w, templName, someDataForTemplate)
```

Comment: Thank you! This was extremely informative! I manually served my .css style sheet separately for now (and it works now!) but I am currently reading ParseFiles and ParseGlob in the specs to do this elegantly as you suggest.

Comment: Thanks for also pointing out the need to avoid parsing inside my handler. I will review.

Answer (score 1):

Templating i.e. generating the HTML which is the body of the HTTP response is totally decoupeled from the content type which is transmitted via a HTTP header. Just set the Content-Type to whatever is appropriate *before* generating the body via `tmpl.Execute(w, ...)` :

```
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/css")
```