# How do I serve CSS and JS in Go

Tags: go, web-applications, server

I followed the [Go Writing Web Applications](https://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/) tutorial but for whatever reason I am having trouble getting the app to serve CSS and JS. If I run my static page without the Go server the page CSS works fine. When I run the Go server on the other hand the CSS just doesn't work.

Here is what my HTML sort of looks like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/custom.css">
```

then under the `body` tag:

```
<script src="../assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

My file tree looks like this:

```
go-affect/
├── data
│   └── …
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   └── …
│   └── js
│   │   └── …
├── tmpl
│   ├── edit.html
│   ├── index.html
│   └── view.html
└── main.go
```

How do I get my Go application to serve the CSS and JavaScript I need?

**EDIT:**

The problem has since been solved, here is the working main:

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/view/", makeHandler(viewHandler))
    http.HandleFunc("/edit/", makeHandler(editHandler))
    http.HandleFunc("/save/", makeHandler(saveHandler))
    http.HandleFunc("/index/", makeHandler(indexHandler))

    
    http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))))

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

Here is an example of the handlers I am using:

```
func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, title string) {
    p := &Page{Title: title}
    err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", p)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include js file in Go template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28899675/include-js-file-in-go-template/28899786#28899786); and [With golang webserver where does the root of the website map onto the filesystem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28745161/with-golang-webserver-where-does-the-root-of-the-website-map-onto-the-filesystem/28745280#28745280)

Comment: Why is the link in html tag is "/assets/" but in the pic "/static/"?

Comment: Can I ask where you put your executable file? I'm having the same problem and I don't know how I should write the file path.

Comment: A Wonderful tutorial https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/serving-static-sites-with-go

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("css/")))
```

Would serve your `css` directory at `/`. Of course you can serve whichever directory at whatever path you choose.

You probably want to make sure that the static path isn't in the way of other paths and use something like this.

```
http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static"))))
```

Placing both your `js` and `css` in the directory `static` in your project. This would then serve them at `domain.com/static/css/filename.css` and `domain.com/static/js/filename.js`

The `StripPrefix` method removes the prefix, so it doesn't try to search e.g. in the `static` directory for `static/css/filename.css` which, of course, it wouldn't find. It would look for `css/filename.css` in the `static` directory, which would be correct.

Comment: Where should I place that line of code? In main with all the function handlers or in my function that serves the index template for example

Comment: Anytime. Usually before `http.ListenAndServe`. So probably in your main.

Comment: Doing it that way does not seem to have worked. I posted some updated code

Comment: Use either the `/static/` path I added to my answer, or do one for each css and js, e.g. `http.Handle("/css/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("css/")))` and `http.Handle("/js/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("js/")))`

Comment: You may need to use `http.StripPrefix` also to get the path right

Comment: @JohnWeldon I just realized that

Comment: I tried replaced the http handle line with both http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/static")))) and http.Handle("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static/"))) but still no luck. I also renamed the assets file to static so that the path names would be correct. My new screenshot reflects that change. I also added that line of code to the main function snippet above

Comment: Your code shows you are using `http.Dir("/static")`. Remove the `/`. Using it tells Go to look for the directory at the root of your filesystem. No `/` tells it to look relative to the go application. Admittedly... my example has the slash, so that's my bad (fixed)

Answer (score 1):

I added a link to my apache servers css dir into the head section of my template files. I keep the template and data files used by any go application under dir that the go application is running from. In this instance cgi-bin.

The template uses the css from my apache server `assets/css` directory  :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/main.css" />
```

[go apps run from my cgi-bin dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOyWi.png)

[sytle sheets are served from my apache assets/css dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmMRl.png)