# Serving Subdirectories in HTTP handlers [GoLang]

Tags: go, gorilla, negroni

I have the following code:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./frontend/build/")))
r.Handle("/static", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./frontend/build/static/")))
r.PathPrefix("/api").Handler(auth)
```

`/api` is supposed to be secure. If a user hits `/`, I want them to view the `index.html` in the `PROJECTDIR/frontend` directory.

The frontend directory looks like

```
frontend
    /build
        index.html
        /static
            /js
            /css
            /media
```

The index.html loads all contents from `/static`. No matter how I seem to configure this, when I visit `localhost:3000`, I can get the `index.html` but everything under `/static` is 404'd.

How am I configuring this incorrectly?

Comment: See [this similar QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43601359/how-do-i-serve-css-and-js-in-go-lang)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you want to serve the whole content of the directory "static" on the endpoint /static and you are running a bsd/linux machine the following syntax should work:

```
http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))))
```

Comment: I'm on MacOS (and running on Heroku in build). Assuming you mean the full path to static? This doesn't work. 
 r.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("frontend/build/")))
 http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("frontend/build/static/"))))
 r.PathPrefix("/api").Handler(auth)

Comment: http.Dir("frontend/build/static/") doesn't specify a correct path. You either need to start the path with "/" to signify the root of your machine (so the path would be something like /home/myuser/myapp/static) or with "./" to specify the current directory you are running your app from as the starting point of your path (so if you are running from "/home/myuser/myapp/" the "./" would translated to that)