# Properly serve a CSS file Golang

Tags: html, css, go

I have a CSS file and I am trying to serve it on my Web Server (New with the http package). I have tried

```
http. (ServeFile, and Handle)
```

I have also tried serving it as a template, but the issue is that on the bottom of the HTML page, it prints the CSS. What is the proper way of serving the CSS file without it printing the whole CSS file on the bottom of the page?

Comment: You can do sonething like this:
https://github.com/google/shenzhen-go/blob/master/cmd/shenzhen-go/main.go
https://github.com/google/shenzhen-go/blob/master/view/static.go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always do this:

```
http.HandleFunc("/game.css", serveCss)
```

and this:

```
func serveCss(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(w, r, "client/game.css")
}
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You can try this instead.

```
http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("css/")))
```

Let me know if it helped you to your problem.

Comment: I get a panic -- panic: http: multiple registrations for /. Would I place this somewhere specifically?

Comment: I guess that's an issue due to vendoring. Anyway you can refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43601359/how-do-i-serve-css-and-js-in-go-lang).