# Style.css imported with GO gives a MIME error

Tags: css, go

I just started learning go and 1 of the things I really wanna learn to do is making sites in go. I watched some tutorials for it and making sites worked, but I didn't know how to add styles.

I searched for some examples on the internet and stackoverflow, but couldn't find one that actually worked for me (and stayed simple).

Underneath is the code that I ended up with.
But I think I got a new problem now cause in the console it says: 
[image: error]

I tried a lot of solutions that I found on the internet for this but none of them worked so I am pretty sure it is because I imported the css wrongly in go.

**Go (functions.go):**

```
package main

import (
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

type IndexPage struct {
    Title string
    SubTitle string
}

func indexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    p := IndexPage{Title: "Pizza site", SubTitle: "everyone loves pizzas"} 
    t, _ := template.ParseFiles("index.html")
    t.Execute(w,p)
}

func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/", indexHandler)
    http.Handle("/css/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("css")))
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

**Html (index.html):**

```
<html lang="nl">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Pizzaaaaaaa</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <article>
        <h1>
            {{ .Title }}
            <span class="subtitle">{{ .SubTitle }}</span>
        </h1>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </article>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS ( /css/style.css )**

```
*{
    color: rgb(250, 157, 157);
}
```

**FileTree**

[image: FileTree]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43601392/9312230 this probably will help you. TL;DR; this code to serve file will resolve your issue `http.Handle("/css/", http.StripPrefix("/css/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("css"))))`

Comment: oh, I saw this post and copied that code ones. I just thought the stripPrefix and all that stuff was unnecessary code so deleted that part. O.o

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your handle return 404 when you try to access css file from this url: `/css/*`

Change your css handle with this:

```
    http.Handle("/css/", http.StripPrefix("/css/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./css"))))
```

*You got 'text/plain' because the 404 is a plain text.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add the mime type for css files in your response header.

```
    if strings.HasSuffix(path, ".css") {
        w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "text/css")
    }
```

Or something similar with a variable for multiple different mime types.

EDIT:

Please also check this go lang package to include for better mime type handling:

https://golang.org/pkg/mime/

Comment: This kinda goes above my knowledge that I have till now. `http.Handle("/css/", http.StripPrefix("/css/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("css"))))`  from the answer from @ttomlak was the solution

Comment: MIME-type wasn't the real issue in your code. It returned that because on `/css/style.css` something like `404 not found` was returned which is `plaintext`

Comment: Well, I don't see a 404 in that console. And you should **always** provide the mime type.